Modal not Closing After Response in React
I'm using useImperativeHandle and ref to let the parent have access to some functions.
I'm wondering why the modal here is not closing? I tried to place alert and console.log and it works but the setIsEditOpen() and setIsDeleteOpen() is not working inside the closeModals.
STACKBLITZ
Product.tsx
export default function Products() {
    const { products } = useLoaderData<typeof loader>();
    const actionData = useActionData<typeof action>();
    const productItemRef = useRef<ModalRef>(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (actionData?.ok) {
            productItemRef?.current.closeModals();
        }
      }, [actionData]);

    return (
        <div className="divide-y">
            {products.map((product) => (
                <ProductItem
                    key={product.id}
                    product={product}
                    ref={productItemRef}
                    lastResult={actionData}
                />
            ))}
        </div>
    )

ProductItem.tsx
type ProductItemProps = {
    product: {
        id: string;
        name: string;
        description: string;
        price: number;
        category: string;
    };
    lastResult?: any;
};

export type ModalRef = {
    closeModals: () => void;
};

export const ProductItem = forwardRef(
    ({ product, lastResult }: ProductItemProps, ref: Ref<ModalRef>) => {
        const [isEditOpen, setIsEditOpen] = useState(false);
        const [isDeleteOpen, setIsDeleteOpen] = useState(false);
        const { name, description, price, category } = product;

        useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
            closeModals: () => {
                setIsEditOpen(false);
                setIsDeleteOpen(false);
            },
        }));

        return (
            <>
                <ReusableSheet
                    isOpen={isEditOpen}
                    setIsOpen={setIsEditOpen}
                    title="Edit a product"
                >
                    <EditProductForm
                        setIsOpen={setIsEditOpen}
                        product={product}
                        lastResult={lastResult}
                    />
                </ReusableSheet>
                <ReusableDialog
                    isOpen={isDeleteOpen}
                    setIsOpen={setIsDeleteOpen}
                    title="Remove a product from the list"
                    description={
                        <span>
                            Are you sure you want to remove{" "}
                            <span className="font-bold">{name}</span>{" "}
                            from the list of products?
                        </span>
                    }
                    hideCloseButton
                >
                    <DeleteProductForm setIsOpen={setIsDeleteOpen} product={product} />
                </ReusableDialog>
            </>
        );
    },
);


Not that I think this is the problem, but it seems your useImperativeHandle hook is missing a dependency array. Try adding one, i.e. useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({ ... }), []);. Otherwise what you have looks fine. Can you create a running sandbox demo?

If i understand correctly, your code has a single productItemRef for all products. So each productItem will override the closeModals. This means your call from the parent component will only call the last item's methods.

@DrewReese. i’ll try to create one when I get back. If i try to call it on the parent on a button onclick, it works. But it doesn’t open on if on the useEffect. Do you think that adding a dependency array would work. I tried to put a console.log inside the closeModals on the useImperativeHandle and it logs it but the setIsEditOpen doesn’t work

You can look at this section of the documentation to manage multiple ref. https://react.dev/learn/manipulating-the-dom-with-refs#how-to-manage-a-list-of-refs-using-a-ref-callback

@Joseph not sure what the expected behavior is. If you can only have only one modal open, than you could set the closeModals only after opening one, so that the closeModals uses the methods of the currently open. If there can be multiple dialogs open you should either use an array of refs and pass the Nth ref to the Nth item or you could use a single ref that uses an array and each item pushes in it its own closeModals in it.

@DrewReese, I've replicated it. Pls see this stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/remix-run-remix-d39w6j?file=app%2Froutes%2F_index.tsx,app%2Fcomponents%2FProductItem.tsx. After clicking save, only one item works

@GabrielePetrioli. There can only be one Dialog to open.

Issue
You are creating and referencing only a single React ref in the products file and passing it to each mapped ProductItem from the products array. This means that each <ProductItem ref={productItemRef} .... /> overwrites the ref value and the last item mapped is what productItemRef has a reference to. When you are clicking the "save" button of say the "Banana" product edit modal, the ref is trying to call closeModals of the "Mango" product edit modal, and the "Banana" modal is never closed.
Solution Suggestion
Creating the Modal Refs
At a minimum you'll need to create a React ref for each mapped ProductItem so they can be individually referenced.
Example:
// Array of React refs
const productItemRef = useRef<React.RefObject<ModalRef>[]>([]);

// Set modal refs to current value or create if necessary
productItemRef.current = products.map(
  (_, i) => productItemRef.current[i] ?? createRef()
);

...

return (
  <div className="flex flex-col gap-2">
    {products.map((product, i) => (
      <ProductItem
        key={product.id}
        product={product}
        ref={productItemRef.current[i]} // <-- pass modal ref
      />
    ))}
  </div>
);

Closing the Modals
A naive/trivial approach could be to simply iterate the entire array of modal refs and call closeModals on each one.
Example:
useEffect(() => {
  if (actionData?.type === 'success') {
    productItemRef.current.forEach((productRef) =>
      productRef.current?.closeModals()
    );
  }
}, [actionData]);

An improved approach would be to include the edited product id in the action data.
Example:
EditProductForm - Include a hidden field that passes the product.Id in the form data, accessible in the action handler.
export function EditProductForm({ setIsOpen, product }: EditProductFormProps) {
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  const isUpdating =
    navigation.formData?.get('intent') === 'edit-product' &&
    navigation.state === 'submitting';

  return (
    <Form method="post">
      <div className="flex justify-end gap-2 mt-2">

        {/* Hidden field to include with form data */}
        <input name="productId" defaultValue={product.id} hidden />

        {product.name}
        <Button
          type="button"
          variant="outline"
          disabled={isUpdating}
          onClick={() => setIsOpen(false)}
        >
          Cancel
        </Button>
        <Button
          name="intent"
          value="edit-product"
          disabled={isUpdating}
          type="submit"
        >
          {isUpdating ? (
            <Loader2 className="mr-2 h-4 w-4 animate-spin" />
          ) : null}
          Save
        </Button>
      </div>
    </Form>
  );
}

Product index file - Access the product id and return with JSON data response.
export const action = async ({ request, context }: ActionFunctionArgs) => {
  const formData = await request.formData();
  const productId = formData.get("productId"); // <-- get product id
  const intent = formData.get('intent');

  if (intent === 'edit-product') {
    return json({
      productId, // <-- return product id
      type: 'success',
    });
  }

  return null;
};

Close just the product edit modal that was open
useEffect(() => {
  if (actionData?.type === 'success') {
    productItemRef.current[
      products.findIndex((product) => product.id === actionData?.productId)
    ].current?.closeModals();
  }
}, [actionData]);


If I'll choose the last part, the productItemRef.current[       products.findIndex((product) => product.id === actionData?.productId)     ].current?.closeModals(); , do I need to adjust the ref above like const productItemRef = useRef<React.RefObject<ModalRef>[]>([]);?

@Joseph Yes, you need the array of refs in any case, to reference individual ProductItem components' exposed refs.
